# Can I include an append on a Laravel 5 model that relies on other appends?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using the `appends` property (and associated getter methods) to load additional information on a model in Laravel 5.5. However, one of the appends (`percentage`) depends on the other two appends (`current_score` and `maximum_score`) already having been loaded and calculated.

What this means, is that in order to include `percentage` as an append and have that property be accurate, the `maximum_score` and `current_score` properties need to be calculated first.

In other words, if I write my `appends` array like so:

```
protected $appends = [
    'maximum_score',
    'current_score',
    'score_percentage',
];
```

Can I reliably know that that order will be respected? IE, can I *know* that the `maximum_score` and `current_score` properties will *always* be set before `score_percentage`, allowing me to use them both to calculate the percentage? Or is there some other way I should be handling this?

Comment: Are these three calculated values calculated in via a getter attribute method ?

Comment: Yes you can. But it's not about the order. Even if you load score_percentage first (or even the only one) it will inevitably call the other 2 and thus "load" them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work no matter what order you put them in.